# After effects loop part of movie clip

Tags: after-effects

I have one movie clip and it has few events which I want to repeat for few times. I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyqgX6l4wNc) and similar other tutorial to achieve this. Ideally I tried following,

1. Select Clip and Pre-compose it (so that I can use that repeating
   part independently. I have tried without pre-compose also and got
   same result)
2. Right click > time > enable time-remapping
3. Goto the expression panel (alt click clock symbol)
4. Put expression as `loopOut()` and click outside
5. Create keyframe between between start and end of my desired clip part

However, this doesn't work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

To better explain the my desired output, lets assume I have 5 min video clip (===) and I want part from 3 to 4 min (+++) to repeat 2 times.

> 0 ====3+++4====5

So now my video should become 6 min with clip from 3 to 4 min repeated twice.

> 0 ====3+++4+++5====6

I am using Adobe After Effects CC 2019.

Answer (score 1):

`LoopOut()` loops after the last keyframe, and by default it loops all the keyframes. Unless you have a specific need to use expressions, this would be easier to achieve by just setting keyframes.

- Once you have time remapping enabled, go to the 3 minute mark and add a keyframe.
- Then go to the frame *one frame before* 4 minute mark and add another.
- Select the last three keyframes (3 minutes, 4 minutes and 5 minutes in your example).
- Copy them <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>.
- Delete the last keyframe
- Park the playhead one frame after the 4 minute keyframe and paste <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>. The 3 minute keyframe should be at the exact 4 minute mark. Since the timing of the subsequent keyframes is undisturbed, the video will run at the right speed.

Your keyframes should look like this:

```
0=====3+++④3+++④=====5 ←keyframes 
0.....3....4....5....6 ←time
```

(the ④ indicates the frame one frame before the four minute mark)

- for extra credit change the first 4 minute keyframe (the one that has the 3 minute keyframe right after it) to a hold keyframe (Right-click and **Toggle Hold Keyframe**). This is because if you have motion blur or frame blending on it can cause strangeness as the layer is "rewound" between the two keyframes.